# Is there a way to truncate table that has foreign a key?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, foreign-key, ddl, truncate

Is there a way to truncate table that has foreign keys ? Delete and reseed can take too long. Is deleting and recreating keys only way ? If so is there a tool that does this ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, you either need to delete and re-create the keys, or wait for the delete and re-seed. Disabling the foreign key temporarily might make the delete faster, but it still won't allow a truncate.

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tablename] NOCHECK CONSTRAINT ALL;

-- delete, reseed, etc.

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tablename] WITH CHECK CHECK CONSTRAINT ALL;
```

Very easy to automate this by building dynamic SQL from the metadata tables, depending on exactly which table(s) you need to target. The above is *just a sample* to demonstrate how it is done for a single table. For example, this will do so for each table that is the target of a foreign key and has an `IDENTITY` column:

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @sql = N'SET NOCOUNT ON;';

;WITH s(t) AS
 (
   SELECT 
     QUOTENAME(OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(referenced_object_id)) 
     + '.' + QUOTENAME(OBJECT_NAME(referenced_object_id))
  FROM sys.foreign_keys AS k
  WHERE EXISTS 
  (
    SELECT 1 FROM sys.identity_columns 
    WHERE [object_id] = k.referenced_object_id
  )
  GROUP BY referenced_object_id
)
SELECT @sql = @sql + N'
  ALTER TABLE ' + t + ' NOCHECK CONSTRAINT ALL;
  DELETE ' + t + ';
  DBCC CHECKIDENT(''' + t + ''', RESEED, 0) WITH NO_INFOMSGS;
  ALTER TABLE ' + t + 'WITH CHECK CHECK CONSTRAINT ALL;'
FROM s;

PRINT @sql;
-- EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

It may be that the output gets truncated, but this is just a limitation of `PRINT` (8K) - the actual command is complete.

PS this assumes SQL Server 2005 or better. Always useful to specify your version as part of your question (usually with a tag).

Comment: While developing, to clear and set new test data.

Comment: @IvanP: Assuming this is part of an automated process, it's fairly simple to identify which tables have FKs.  `DROP` those first, then recreate your schema in reverse order.

Comment: Script must be updated for every change in table, don't need that.

Comment: I thought you were talking about static script and recreating whole table structure.

Comment: I thought [we're not supposed to do variable concatentation](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/132709/220697)

Comment: No, I realized that you might not have known. Was just wondering whether to edit this answer which I came across recently, but wouldn't be so rude as to do it without asking. By the way, the problem can also manifest in joined queries and parallel plans.