# How to order by COALESCE by some fields?

Tags: sql-server

Let says I've this query:

```
DECLARE @QueryString NVARCHAR(MAX) ;
SELECT @QueryString = COALESCE(@QueryString + ' UNION ALL ','')
                      + 'SELECT '
                      + '''' + QUOTENAME(SCHEMA_NAME(sOBJ.schema_id))
                      + '.' + QUOTENAME(sOBJ.name) + '''' + ' AS [TableName]
                      , COUNT(*) AS [RowCount] FROM '
                      + QUOTENAME(SCHEMA_NAME(sOBJ.schema_id))
                      + '.' + QUOTENAME(sOBJ.name) + ' WITH (NOLOCK) '
FROM sys.objects AS sOBJ
WHERE
      sOBJ.type = 'U'
      AND sOBJ.is_ms_shipped = 0x0
ORDER BY SCHEMA_NAME(sOBJ.schema_id), sOBJ.name ;
EXEC sp_executesql @QueryString
GO
```

which extract all tables of a database, and the number of records on each table.

The question is pretty easy, but can't find how to do it :) How can I order by TableName? Or RowCount?

Putting it on order by clause give me error (i.e. *Incorrect syntax near 'SCHEMA_NAME'.*).

Thanks for any fancy tips.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After filling the `@QueryString` you can add your `ORDER BY`.

```
DECLARE @QueryString NVARCHAR(MAX);
SELECT
         @QueryString = COALESCE(@QueryString + ' UNION ALL ', '') + N'SELECT '
                        + N'''' + QUOTENAME(SCHEMA_NAME(sOBJ.schema_id)) + N'.'
                        + QUOTENAME(sOBJ.name) + N''''
                        + N' AS [TableName]
                      , COUNT(*) AS [RowCount] FROM '
                        + QUOTENAME(SCHEMA_NAME(sOBJ.schema_id)) + N'.'
                        + QUOTENAME(sOBJ.name) + N' WITH (NOLOCK) '
FROM     sys.objects AS sOBJ
WHERE    sOBJ.type = 'U'
         AND sOBJ.is_ms_shipped = 0x0
ORDER BY SCHEMA_NAME(sOBJ.schema_id),
         sOBJ.name;

SET @QueryString = @QueryString + N' ORDER BY [TableName], [RowCount]';

EXEC sp_executesql @QueryString;
GO
```

Comment: Works perfect! Thanks

Comment: Please take note of Charlie's addition. The variable coalescing is not adviced to use.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned, you need to just add `ORDER BY` to the dynamic query.

**You shouldn't use variable coalescing** to aggregate, it's a [documented anti-pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/select-local-variable-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#c-antipattern-use-of-recursive-variable-assignment), and in the presence of things like `ORDER BY` it [often gives incorrect results](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/132709/220697).

Instead just use `STRING_AGG` with a `WITHIN GROUP` parameter.

Note also the join to `sys.schemas`, and you can use `sys.tables` rather than filtering `sys.objects` directly.

```sql
DECLARE @QueryString NVARCHAR(MAX);
SELECT @QueryString =
  STRING_AGG(CONVERT(nvarchar(max), '
SELECT
  ''' + REPLACE(QUOTENAME(s.name) + '.' + QUOTENAME(sOBJ.name), '''', '''''') + ''' AS TableName
, COUNT(*) AS RowCount
FROM ' + QUOTENAME(s.name) + '.' + QUOTENAME(sOBJ.name) + ' WITH (NOLOCK)
'),
    'UNION ALL ') WITHING GROUP (ORDER BY s.name, sOBJ.name)

    + '
ORDER BY TableName, RowCount;'

FROM sys.tables AS sOBJ
JOIN sys.schemas s ON s.schema_id = o.schema_id
WHERE sOBJ.is_ms_shipped = 0;

EXEC sp_executesql @QueryString;
```

Note also that if you don't mind getting slightly inaccurate figures, there are [much faster ways](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6069288/14868997) of getting full table counts.

---

On older versions of SQL Server, you don't have `STRING_AGG` so you need the classic hack with `FOR XML PATH` to get the same thing, and `STUFF` to knock off the extra separator.

```sql
DECLARE @separator nvarchar(100) = 'UNION ALL ';

DECLARE @QueryString NVARCHAR(MAX);
SELECT @QueryString = STUFF((
  SELECT
    @separator + '
SELECT
  ''' + REPLACE(QUOTENAME(s.name) + '.' + QUOTENAME(sOBJ.name), '''', '''''') + ''' AS TableName
, COUNT(*) AS RowCount
FROM ' + QUOTENAME(s.name) + '.' + QUOTENAME(sOBJ.name) + ' WITH (NOLOCK)
')

    FROM sys.tables AS sOBJ
    JOIN sys.schemas s ON s.schema_id = o.schema_id
    WHERE sOBJ.is_ms_shipped = 0
    ORDER BY s.name, sOBJ.name
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
).value('text()[1]', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, LEN(@separator), '') + '
ORDER BY TableName, RowCount;';

EXEC sp_executesql @QueryString;
```

Comment: It says 'STRING_AGG' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: Then you are on an old version of SQL Server. You can use `FOR XML PATH` instead, see edit